# Magento Pager is not showing custom attributes in product products-list.phtml

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, template

I'm facing a coding problem using Magento. I want to display the detail of a product in a recently bought template from TemplateMonster. I have created two numerical custom attributes in my product table in the database (namely `PP` and `PR`). The scope of the attributes is global in admin panel. I just can't display those two attributes on my page. 
I'm using the following code, above the price display:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getAttributeText("pp") ?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getAttributeText("pr") ?>
```

The attributes don't appear anywhere. I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Nuno you got the answer ?

Comment: is that in magento1 or magento2 ?

Comment: It is Magento 2 but with an awful new template from template monster. I just can't figure out how they code it.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this code**

```
echo $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('Your_Attribute_Code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('pp')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item); ?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('pr')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item); ?>
```

Comment: I tried so and doesn't seem to work, I don't know why. It seems that the page encapsulates the data in some way I can't access the state of the attributes. Nothing appear in my result page

Comment: Check your collection, I mean all attributes added for `addAttributeToSelect` with `*` for few fields only.

Comment: I'm new with Magento. How can I do that in practice?

Comment: can you share your  PHTML file content?

Answer (score 0):

My products-list.phtml code is as following:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying new products widget
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget
 */
if ($exist = ($block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getItems())) {
    $type = 'widget-new-list';

    $mode = 'list';
    $widgetType = $block->getProductTypes();

    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_list';
    $title = $block->getTitle();
    $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();
    $label = $block->getWidgetLabel();
    $isCarousel = $block->getShowCarousel();
    $visibleCarousel = $block->getNumberToDisplay();
    $productItemWidth = $block->getItemWidth();
    $productPp = $block->getPp();
    $productPr = $block->getPr();


    $showReviews = [
        'new_product'         => false,
        'sale_product'        => false,
        'viewed_product'      => false,
        'bestsellers_product' => false,
        'rated_product'       => true,
        'manual_product'      => false
    ];

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    $description = true;
}
?>

<?php ?>

<?php if ($exist):?>
    <div class="block widget featured <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $widgetType; ?> one-product-carousel">
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong role="heading" aria-level="2"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($title); ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content<?php echo $productItemWidth ? ' custom-columns' : '' ?>">

            <div class="products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?>">
                <div class="product-items <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $type; ?> <?php if ($isCarousel): ?>owl-carousel<?php endif; ?>"
                    <?php if ($isCarousel): ?>
                        data-mage-init='{"carousel": {"items": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $visibleCarousel; ?>"}}'
                    <?php endif; ?>>
                    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<div class="product-item"' . ' ' . $productItemWidth . '>'
                            : '</div><div class="product-item"' . ' ' . $productItemWidth . '>' ?>
                    <div class="container">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo ($block->getShowLabel()) ? '<span class="product-label">' . $label . '</span>' : ''; ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info">

                            <div class="product-item-details">
                                <div class="opw-left-side">
                                    <strong class="product-item-name">
                                        <a title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                           href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"
                                           class="product-item-link">
                                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </strong>

                                    <?php if ($description):?>
                                        <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getShortDescription(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>


                                <div class="opw-right-side">
                                    <?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type); ?>
                                    <!--div class="points-box"-->


                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('pp')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item); ?>
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('pr')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item); ?>

                                      <!--'<div  class="points-box"> PP ' . $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('pp') .
                                      : '</div><div class="points-box" > PR ' . $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('pr') . '</div>' ?-->

                                      <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                        <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType, $showReviews[$widgetType]) ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="product-item-actions">
                                            <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                                    <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                        <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                            <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                                    data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl":{"url":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}'
                                                                    type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        <?php else: ?>
                                                            <?php
                                                            $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                            $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                            ?>
                                                            <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                                    data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postData; ?>'
                                                                    type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                        <?php else: ?>
                                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare): ?>
                                                <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && $showWishlist): ?>
                                                        <a href="#"
                                                           data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item); ?>'
                                                           class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?>">
                                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl() && $showCompare): ?>
                                                        <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');?>
                                                        <a href="#" class="action tocompare"
                                                           data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item);?>'
                                                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?>">
                                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>



                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                                <?php echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <?php echo($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</div>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getPagerHtml() ?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Somehow the page encapsulates its attributes in their own objects and I just can't decrypt the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to configure the 'getters' in Product page (Product.php) in order to access the value of the attributes. Unsuccessfully.

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 TemplateMonster. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 *
 */

namespace TemplateMonster\FeaturedProduct\Block\FeaturedProduct\Widget;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{

    /**
     * Default cache time
     */
    const CACHE_TIME = 86400;

    protected $_template = 'TemplateMonster_FeaturedProduct::widget/products.phtml';
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_imageBuilder;
    protected $_httpContext;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \TemplateMonster\FeaturedProduct\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_imageBuilder = $context->getImageBuilder();
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(
            ['cache_lifetime' => self::CACHE_TIME, 'cache_tags' => [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG]]
        );
        parent::_construct();
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $cacheKeyFromData = "TM_";
        $configData = $this->getData();

        foreach($configData as $value) {
            if(is_string($value)) {
                $cacheKeyFromData .= $value;

            }
        }
        return [
            $cacheKeyFromData,
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
            $this->_httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP),
            'template' => $this->getTemplate()
        ];
    }

    public function getCacheLifetime()
    {
        if(!$this->getData('cache_lifetime')) {
            return self::CACHE_TIME;
        }
        return $this->getData('cache_lifetime');
    }

    public function getProductIds()
    {
        $productArr = [];
        $productIdsStr = $this->getData('product_ids');
        if($productIdsStr && is_string($productIdsStr)) {
            $productArr = explode(',',$productIdsStr);
        }
        return $productArr;
    }

    public function getItemWidth()
    {
        $productItemWidth = '';
        $productPerRow = $this->getNumberPerRow();
        if ($productPerRow) {
            if (!$this->getShowCarousel()) {
                $productItemWidth = 'style="width: ' . 100 / $productPerRow . '%;"';
            }
        }
        return $productItemWidth;
    }

    public function getPp()
    {
        $productPp = $this->getData('pp');
        return 'PP ' . $productPp;
    }

   public function getPr()
    {
        $productPp = $this->getData('pr');
        return 'PR ' . $productPp;
    }

    /**
     * Return Product Collection
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $productIds = $this->getProductIds();
        $numberPerView = (int)$this->getNumberPerView();
        $productType = $this->getProductTypes();
        try {
            $productFactory = $this->_productFactory->create($productType);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        $productCollection = $productFactory->getPreparedCollection($numberPerView,$productIds);
        return $productCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Return HTML block with price
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param string $priceType
     * @param string $renderZone
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function getProductPriceHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $priceType = null,
        $renderZone = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
        array $arguments = []
    ) {
        if (!isset($arguments['zone'])) {
            $arguments['zone'] = $renderZone;
        }
        $arguments['zone'] = isset($arguments['zone'])
            ? $arguments['zone']
            : $renderZone;
        $arguments['price_id'] = isset($arguments['price_id'])
            ? $arguments['price_id']
            : 'old-price-' . $product->getId() . '-' . $priceType;
        $arguments['include_container'] = isset($arguments['include_container'])
            ? $arguments['include_container']
            : true;
        $arguments['display_minimal_price'] = isset($arguments['display_minimal_price'])
            ? $arguments['display_minimal_price']
            : true;

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');

        $price = '';
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render(
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $product,
                $arguments
            );
        }
        return $price;
    }

/**
     * Return HTML block with price
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param string $priceType
     * @param string $renderZone
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function getProductPriceHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $priceType = null,
        $renderZone = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
        array $arguments = []
    ) {
        if (!isset($arguments['zone'])) {
            $arguments['zone'] = $renderZone;
        }
        $arguments['zone'] = isset($arguments['zone'])
            ? $arguments['zone']
            : $renderZone;
        $arguments['price_id'] = isset($arguments['price_id'])
            ? $arguments['price_id']
            : 'old-price-' . $product->getId() . '-' . $priceType;
        $arguments['include_container'] = isset($arguments['include_container'])
            ? $arguments['include_container']
            : true;
        $arguments['display_minimal_price'] = isset($arguments['display_minimal_price'])
            ? $arguments['display_minimal_price']
            : true;

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');

        $price = '';
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render(
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $product,
                $arguments
            );
        }
        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

}
```